# XNA programming a platformer

Tags: c#, xna

"Rem ad Triarios redisse" Scipio Africanus
I'm programming a platformer and I'm working on the collision, but when it collides a get a stack overflow error;I can't figure it out myself and I would be thankfull if someone knew how to fix it.
The code of the class(main concern):

```
                               public class Colliding
                  {
                         Rectangle testCollide;

    Vector2 playerposition, objectPosition;
    Texture2D objectPic;
    bool jump;
    public Rectangle TestCollide
    {
        get { return TestCollide; }
        set { testCollide = value; }
    }
    public Vector2 ObjectPosition
    {
        get { return objectPosition; }
        set { objectPosition = value; }
    }
    public Vector2 Return
    {
        get { return objectPosition; }
    }
    public Texture2D ObjectPic
    {
        set { objectPic = value; }
    }
    public bool Bool
    {
        get { return jump; }
    }
    public void Update()
    {

        /*if (testCollide.Contains(new Point((int)objectPosition.X, (int)objectPosition.Y + (int)objectPic.Height)) && !
        testCollide.Contains(new Point((int)objectPosition.X, (int)objectPosition.Y + (int)objectPic.Height)))
        {
            objectPosition = new Vector2(objectPosition.X, testCollide.Top - objectPic.Height);
            jump = false;
        }*/
        if (testCollide.Contains(new Point((int)objectPosition.X + (int)objectPic.Width, (int)objectPosition.Y))&&
            testCollide.Contains(new Point((int)objectPosition.X + (int)objectPic.Width, (int)objectPosition.Y)))
        {
            objectPosition = new Vector2(TestCollide.Right - objectPic.Width, ObjectPosition.Y);
            jump = false;
        }
        if (testCollide.Contains(new Point((int)objectPosition.X , (int)objectPosition.Y)) && 
        testCollide.Contains(new Point((int)objectPosition.X , (int)objectPosition.Y)))
        {
            objectPosition = new Vector2(TestCollide.Left +1 , ObjectPosition.Y);
            jump = false;
        }
```

The Code of my main(a little messy at the moment)

```
       public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
     {
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    KeyboardState keyState;
    KeyboardState prevKeyState;
    Texture2D flour,nonAnimPlayer;
    Rectangle ground1,ground2,playerRect;
    Vector2 playerPosition;

    float jumpspeed;
    int screenX = 800;
    int screenY=480;
    float standardMoveSpeed;
    bool jumping;

    Colliding colGround1=new Colliding ();
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = screenX;
        this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = screenY;
    }
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        ground1 = new Rectangle(-100, (screenY / 5) * 4, 300,screenY);
        ground2 = new Rectangle(400, (screenY / 5) * 4, 800, screenY);
        playerRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
        standardMoveSpeed = 300;

        base.Initialize();
    }
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        flour = Content.Load<Texture2D>("background");
        nonAnimPlayer = Content.Load<Texture2D>("blok");
    }
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        prevKeyState = keyState;
        keyState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            playerPosition.X += standardMoveSpeed *(float) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            playerPosition.X -= standardMoveSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)&&prevKeyState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space ))
        {
            if (jumpspeed == 0)
                jumpspeed = 300;
            else
                jumpspeed += 35;
            jumping = true;
        }

        playerPosition.Y += standardMoveSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        if(jumping)
        {
            playerPosition.Y -= standardMoveSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds+jumpspeed*(float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds ;
            jumpspeed-=9;
            if (jumpspeed <= 0)
                jumping = false;
        }

        if (ground2.Contains(new Point((int)playerPosition.X, (int)playerPosition.Y + (int)nonAnimPlayer.Height)))
        {
            playerPosition.Y = ground2.Top - nonAnimPlayer.Height;
            jumpspeed = 0;

        }

        colGround1.ObjectPosition = playerPosition;
        colGround1.TestCollide = ground1;
        colGround1.ObjectPic = nonAnimPlayer;
        colGround1.Update();
        playerPosition = colGround1.Return;
        if (colGround1.Bool)
            jumpspeed = 0;

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(flour, ground1, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(flour, ground2, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(nonAnimPlayer, playerPosition, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
```

Comment: TestCollide's Getter returns itself. Change it to a lowercase t (testCollide), and the Stack Overflow exception should be fixed.

Comment: thanks for your help, but i already fixed it myself